# NullReferenceException when assigning a Session variable/value

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, session, nullreferenceexception

I have in many places in  my ASP.NET project used the Session variable for storing data. I usually write something like this:

```
public uint MyPropery 
{
    get 
    {
        object o = Session["MyProperty"];
        if (o != null)
            return (uint)o;
        else
            return 0;
    }
    set 
    {
        Session["MyProperty"] = value;
    }
}
```

However, this time I get a NullReferenceException in the setter. As far as I know, it is valid to assign the Session variable in the manner above. Also, Session is not null and neither is value.

Any ideas on this?

**Edit:**

Adding the code for the UserControl in which the property exists. I am using ext.net but that shouldn't have anything to do with this. One thought that crossed my mind:

The UserControl (seen below) is added dynamically in code-behind of a page. Can that have anything to do with it?

I am adding UserControls like this  (on a Page):

```
foreach(CoreCommons.System.Comment c in cg.Reply_Comments)
{
    WebApplicationExtNetTest.Secure.UserControls.CoreComment cc = new UserControls.CoreComment();
    cc._Comment = c; // here is where i get the NullRef
    this.Panel1.ContentControls.Add(cc);
}
```

*Markup:*

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="CoreComment.ascx.cs" Inherits="WebApplicationExtNetTest.Secure.UserControls.CoreComment" %>
<%@ Register Assembly="Ext.Net" Namespace="Ext.Net" TagPrefix="ext" %>

<ext:Panel runat="server" ID="CoreCommentOuterPanel" BodyStyle="background: #FFFDDE">
    <Items>
        <ext:ColumnLayout runat="server">
            <Columns>
                <ext:LayoutColumn ColumnWidth="0.8">
                    <ext:Image runat="server" ImageUrl="/Resources/bullet_triangle_green_16x16.png" Align="AbsMiddle"></ext:Image> 
                    <ext:Label runat="server" ID="lblCommentInfo"></ext:Label>
                </ext:LayoutColumn>
                <ext:LayoutColumn ColumnWidth="0.2"><ext:Button runat="server" ID="btnDelete" Icon="Delete"></ext:Button></ext:LayoutColumn>
            </Columns>
        </ext:ColumnLayout>
        <ext:Label runat="server" ID="lblComment"></ext:Label>
    </Items>
</ext:Panel>
```

*Code-behind:*

```
namespace WebApplicationExtNetTest.Secure.UserControls
{
    public partial class CoreComment : System.Web.UI.UserControl
    {
        public CoreCommons.System.Comment _Comment
        {
            get
            {
                object o = Session["CoreComment_ObjectId"];
                if (o != null)
                    return (tWorks.Core.CoreCommons.System.Comment)o;
                else
                    return null;
            }
            set
            {
                Session["CoreComment_ObjectId"] = value;
                SetComment();
            }
        }            

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {    
        }

        private void SetComment()
        {
            if (_Comment == null)
            {
                lblCommentInfo.Text = "";
                lblComment.Text = "";
            }
            else
            {
                lblCommentInfo.Text = _Comment.Author + ", " + _Comment.TimeStamp.ToString("g");
                lblComment.Text = _Comment.Text;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The code you posted looks like it should work. Can you maybe post the actual example that fails?

Comment: i use the same pattern all the time without problem. id say the problem is somewhere else. you could be setting the value when the session doesnt exist

Comment: @SirViver: Its a lot of code, part of a project. It is in a UserControl, and I have updated the post and posted the entire UserControl.

Comment: @Jeff: The session must exist, since I am logged in to the site. Hmm...

Comment: As I write in the updated post: can the problem have anything to do with the fact that Im adding those controls dynamically?

Comment: @Ted just because you are logged in doesnt mean the session exists. for a quick example, session does not exist during a web service request by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm almost completely sure the `NullReferenceException` is thrown in `SetComment()` because none of the `CoreComment`'s child controls (lblComment, lblCommentInfo) are properly instantiated at the point you set the `_Comment` property.

The reason these child controls are not instantiated is indeed the way you currently add the `CoreComment` controls. For dynamically adding UserControls, you must use `Page.LoadControl()` (see: [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c0az2h86.aspx#Y570)) to create a new instance of the control, as it does some behind-the-scenes magic to ensure it is properly initialized, which includes the instantiation of the child controls.

On a sidenote, personally I'd change `SetComment()` to `SetComment(CoreCommons.System.Comment comment)` and use the parameter instead of repeatedly calling the getter, or, if staying with the original, at least call the getter only once and store the result in a local variable. With what I assume is probably InProc session storage it won't make much of a difference, but in any other storage mode you'd repeatedly deserialize the `Comment` object for no reason.

Comment: Thanks. I was told that using the Constructor would work equally good as using LoadControl. I first tried with LoadControl but got another (unrelated) error, so I switched to using the Constructor. And as you say, it seems like using the Constructor doesnt really instantiate the Control very well. 
Now, for some reason, LoadControl works and when I use that the setting of the property also works. Thx =)

Comment: As a note: I havent confirmed your first sentance about the error being in SetComment. Its unlikely ythough, as it breaks before SetComment.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `Page.LoadControl()` method instead , please look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c0az2h86.aspx#Y570)

**BTW**:the problem is in adding the control programatically with that way.

Comment: Indeed. See my comment on SirViver =)

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
return Session["MyProperty"] as uint? ?? 0;
```

and post somewhere full exception stack trace with inner exception(s)